# reading an Nth clock output using a VHDL program

Tags: vhdl

*I have been working on a comparator and have to  get the output of the program at  256th clock.

  How can i get this output value using codes?*

Comment: If you ask for code, please provide information about what you have tried so far. Include some code, and include information about what research you have done to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a `temp` variable of type integer . Increment the its value every-time there is a rising edge of the clock and compare the value of `temp` with `256` when it is `256` simply output the value .